Why is ROM read only? And why do SSDs use it?
I was researching about SSDs and ended up going further and reading about how it uses flash technology which from what I gather is pretty much an EEPROM, which (I might be wrong on this) is just an effective way to hold small amounts of memory non-volatilely. But why is the data really read only? Why can't we easily change it unlike RAM? And why do we use that kind of technology on SSDs if rewriting over it reduces life cycle?

My 2 TB SSD drive wants to tell you that it holds more than just small amounts of non-volatile memory.

In some sense, EEPROM isn't ROM, since you can change it, but in another sense, it's very close to ROM, since it needs a special machine to change it. It's like ROM but better because you can change it. Flash storage (notice they stopped calling it ROM) is even further along that axis, even easier to change than EEPROM, but still harder than changing RAM.

I have no idea where you get this from that an SSD drive is anything like an EEPROM.
EEPROMs are direct access read-only memory, that can be reprogrammed using an EEPROM programmer. The largest sizes available are 4 Megabit. SSD drives come in sizes up to 16 Terabyte. That's about 32 million times more.
Why do we use SSDs and not RAM? First, most computers have no way to handle 1 TB of RAM. If they can, you can expect to pay \$20,000 or so for it. Instead of $100 for an SSD. Second, RAM is volatile. You turn the computer off, all the contents of the RAM is gone. That's not very good when you want to keep anything permanently.
And why is ROM read-only? Because it is literally Read Only Memory.

Flash storage is not read-only.  It can be updated and overwritten.
Because flash storage uses different technology and gates than RAM, write operations are slower and cost more.  This is a result of the physics of the device.
We use flash storage and SSDs instead of hard drives because they are much faster: for instance, you can read from flash storage much faster than a mechanical hard drive.  Also, for laptops, SSDs are smaller and lighter and more resilient to physical shocks.  There is certainly a tradeoff, but the benefits outweigh the disadvantages for many purposes.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Comparison_with_other_technologies.
